# Output error from cart items

Tags: expresso-store

I'm getting an error when trying to call a channel entries tag from inside of {items}. If I remove the channel entries it's fine:

```
{exp:store:checkout}

    {items}

        {exp:channel:entries}
            {title}
        {/exp:channel:entries}

    {/items}

{/exp:store:checkout}
```

The error is just a notice, but an error nonetheless:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: EE::$typography
>
> Filename: core/EE_Output.php
>
> Line Number: 308
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function parse_type() on a non-object in /Sites/mysite.com/source/ee/expressionengine/core/EE_Output.php on line 308

Any suggestions?

This is on EE 2.7.2, latest Store.

Answer (score 2):

When you are looping through the items in your cart/checkout tags you should add `entry_id="{entry_id}"` to the channel entries tag as the `{items}` will allow you to output the entry_id of items in the cart. Your template should look something along the lines of:

```
{exp:store:checkout}
    {items}

        {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}" limit="1" dynamic="no"}
            {title}
        {/exp:channel:entries}

    {/items}
{/exp:store:checkout}
```

Having said that you do not need to use a channel entries loop to get the title, url_title and a bunch of other product related info (you can see the entire list [here](https://exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#items_loop)). You only need to use the channel entries loop if you are trying to grab information that you have stored in other custom fields (images, descriptions, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your `{exp:channel:entries}` into an embed template like this.

**In your main template use:**

```
{exp:store:checkout}
    {items}
        {embed="store/items"}
    {/items}
{/exp:store:checkout}
```

**In your embed template use:**

```
{exp:channel:entries dynamic="no"}
         {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

***** rename "store" to your correct template group name

Comment: I tried that, but get the same issue. And the Store docs state that an inline template should work fine.

Comment: Can you post your full template code please to pastie.org

Comment: When you are looping through the items loop you should have:

`{items}{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}{title}{/exp:channel:entries}{/items}`

Also you do not need to use `{exp:channel:entries}` loop to get the `{title}` element only when you are looping through custom fields

Comment: @JustinLong Can you post your comment as a new answer?

Comment: Yup, I gave a bit more detail too

Comment: Inline channel entries tags will work in simple situations, but if you do run into parse order issues you should always try using an embed as Anna suggests.

Comment: I'm actually getting this from the store's demo templates though with a clean install? 

For example when I click to view a product: store_example/product/example-product.